# Creating an ER database and trying to represent something that is like a relationship with a relationship

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I'm making a database for a personal project and as a part of it, I want to represent certain tables in a specific way.

Basically, I want the user to be able to input their own questions (and allow questions to appear during different "times"). And a user should be able to respond multiple times to a question, while also distinguishing their responses by time.

So, effectively we have four tables: Person, Response, Question, Time.

The way I am envisioning it is there is a relationship between Question and Time, let's call it QT. And then there is a tertiary relationship between Person, Response and QT. That depiction makes the most sense for what I'm looking for, but I don't know if it's legal in ER diagrams, and/or how that would best translate to table form.

Comment: ER diagrams represent n-ary relationships as entities with n binary relationships.  The tables you're envisioning aren't a problem, as long as they accurately represent the facts that you want to record.

Comment: ER diagrams represent n-ary relationships by n-ary relationship diamonds. Lines connecting a diamond to an entity rectangle or relationship diamond do not represent relationships, they represent foreign keys. (Unfortunately those are *called* "relationships" in some ER presentations and tools.) Each ER entity type/set and relationship type/set corresponds to a table. However there are a lot of variant notations. A problem with ER modeling is that it forces one to make needless distinctions between entity types vs relationship types.